# Is there a demo app for VMware Clarity framework?

Tags: vmware-clarity

Is there a demo app for the Clarity framework?

Something that shows off all aspects of the framework,

Comment: We don’t have a stand-alone published app with all of the components in it. There is a dev app in the repository that we use for development and issue triage.

Comment: That's a shame.  The Clarity framework is very interesting, but as most other frameworks have at least one demo app, you are probably selling yourself short.

Comment: Note that its [web app is a demo](https://clarity.design/documentation/grid) app of the framework. Every component has a number of examples. What kind of demo app are you looking for? A Todo example app like http://todomvc.com/ ?